# Ruby API Call Page Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, httparty

This might be a basic issue but very common so it might be helpful to other people in the future. 
I use HTTParty to make a get request to an API, which returns some information, something like this:

```
{
    datapath: "blah-blah.blah.blah",
    success: true,
    info: {
        row_limit: 500, 
        total_results: 2700,
        total_pages: 6, 
        current_page: 1
    }, 
    result: [
        {name: something, age: 1}, 
        {name: something, age: 2}, 
        {name: something, age: 3}, 
        {name: something, age: 4}, 
        {name: something, age: 5}, 
        ......
    ]
}
```

I want a list of all names, so I have something like this:

```
response = HTTParty.get('blah-blah.blah.blah')
names = response.map { |entry| entry["name"] }
```

With this method I only get names on the very first page aka those first 500, but I want all the names in the 2700 entries. How do I do that?

Comment: Is this what you meant to write?  "This method only get names on the very first page, but all names of 2700 entries"  It doesn't really make sense.  Do you mean something like  "This method only gets names on the very first page, but *I want to get* the names of all 2700 entries"?  Please edit your question if so.

Comment: Also, i suspect that the answer varies depending on which API you're using.    What is the API here?

Comment: @MaxWilliams Sorry about the typo. I've edited my question, and yes that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: It sounds like what you need to change with your API call is the page size: set it to something very large like 1000000.  The api documentation should tell you how to do this.  I can see in the results that the row_limit is 500 - this is what you want to change.  So maybe the parameter you need to pass is "row_limit=1000000".  In rails commonly it's "per_page".  Like i said it should be in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, a quick google led me to this page https://app.enigma.io/api#data which tells me the parameter in question is **limit**, and that the max is 500.  So, it looks like you can't get the data for all rows in one hit.

If you really NEED the data for all the rows at once (and maybe you don't, actually) then you can pass limit=500 and keep increasing the **page** by 1, and combine the results at your end to get all the rows.